# Thesis title slide

Tags: beamer, columns, multicolumn

I have to write a presentation for my thesis. I am using beamer. Here is the code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[slidescentered]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\title{Orbite periodiche di flussi Hamiltoniani su ipersuperfici convesse}
\author[Michele Gorini]{\begin{multicols}{2} Candidato \\ Michele Gorini \\\columnbreak Relatore \\ prof. Roberto Paoletti \end{multicols}}
\institute[Unimib]{Università degli studi di Milano-Bicocca}
\date{26 Novembre 2015}
\logo{\includegraphics{Logo.jpg}}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
Use of \begin doesn't match its definition.
\beamer@andstripped ->\begin {
                          multicols}{2} Candidato \\ Michele Gorini \\\c...
l.8 ... \\ prof. Roberto Paoletti \end{multicols}}
```

Desired result:

[image]

Or something similar. Pic obtained with code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[slidescentered]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\title{Orbite periodiche di flussi Hamiltoniani su ipersuperfici convesse}
\author[Michele Gorini]{\hspace{.5cm} Candidato \hspace{3.5cm} Relatore \\ \hspace{1cm} Michele Gorini \hspace{2cm} prof. Roberto Paoletti}
\institute[Unimib]{Università degli studi di Milano-Bicocca}
\date{26 Novembre 2015}
\logo{\includegraphics{Logo.jpg}}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

What is going wrong in the other code and why? And is there a smarter way than random `\hspaces` to get the desired result?

And PS, trying a `tabular` gives more or less the same error, which is why this is tagged [columns](/questions/tagged/columns) too.

**Edit**

I only just realized that the logo is too wide, so I resized it with `[width=1.5cm]`. Anyway you do not have the image, so just use `\rule{5cm}{3cm}` instead of the `\includegraphics`.

And PS I am asking this to avoid ruling the spacing by hand, so I refused my friend's `\quad \qquad\qquad …` solution and would like a solution without spacing commands. Apparently switching to `\twocolumns`, `\begin{multicols}{2}`, `\begin{columns}` or using a `tabular` does not work as seen above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a box to insert the authors. Inside this box, you may use `minipage`s or `tabular`s or native `columns` and `\column` etc. I have used `minipage`s.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[slidescentered]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\newsavebox{\authbox}
\sbox{\authbox}{%
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering\normalsize
Candidato \par
Michele Gorini
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering\normalsize
Relatore \par
prof. Roberto Paoletti
\end{minipage}
}

\title{Orbite periodiche di flussi Hamiltoniani su ipersuperfici convesse}
\author[Michele Gorini]{%
\usebox{\authbox}
}
\institute[Unimib]{Università degli studi di Milano-Bicocca}
\date{26 Novembre 2015}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Time for me to learn what a `minipage` is :).