# Beamer: Is there a cleaner way to implement this titlepage

Tags: beamer

I have the following MWE, taken from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271442/172923), that creates a beamer titlepage showing both the candidate and the supervisor of a thesis

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usefonttheme[stillsansserifsmall,stillsansseriflarge]{serif}

\definecolor{Text}{HTML}{000F1C}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=Text}

\newsavebox{\authbox}
\sbox{\authbox}{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    {\small \textcolor{Text}{\textrm{Candidate:}}} \\
    {\normalsize \textcolor{Text}{\textrm{Foo Bar}}}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    {\small \textcolor{Text}{\textrm{Supervisor:}}} \\
    {\normalsize \textcolor{Text}{\textrm{Prof. Foo Bar Baz}}}
  \end{minipage}
}

\title{An interesting topic}
\author[Me]{\usebox{\authbox}}
\institute{A university}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following

[image]

What I don't like about this implementation is:

1. I have to manually call `\textrm{...}` even though I'm already using the `serif` font theme. A normal `\author{me}` would already be in serif;
2. I have to manually call `\textcolor{Text}` even though I'm alredy setting `fg=Text` for normal text. A normal `\author{me}` would already be colored in `Text`.
3. The two `minipage`s seem to be a shifted to the right. For example, if I substitute the first `\centering` with `\flushleft` and the second one with `\flushright`, this is what I get

[image]

while I'd expect `Candidate` to be lined up with the left side of the title's colorbox, and the end of `Supervisor` to be lined up with right side. Instead, `Candidate` starts a bit to the right of the left side and `Supervisor` ends a bit to the right of the right side.

Is there a way to fix all three of these issues? Is there a completely different implementation that is cleaner and produces the desired results?

Comment: 1. I don't understand `[sansserif]{serif}` and 2. I don't understand beamer colors.  But for 3., my guess is the box is indented.  Have you tried `\noindent` before the first minipage?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't HAVE to use \titlepage.  It is supposed to be a convenience, not an obstacle.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I wouldn't know how to reproduce the rest of the titlepage. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, beamer themes cannot be searched using my usual approach, so I have no idea what colors and spacing it actually uses.  A precise match by trial and error is possible, but tedious.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usefonttheme[stillsansserifsmall,stillsansseriflarge]{serif}

\definecolor{Text}{HTML}{000F1C}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=Text}

\newsavebox{\authbox}
\sbox{\authbox}{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\small \textcolor{Text}{\textrm{Candidate:}}} \\
    {\normalsize \textcolor{Text}{\textrm{Foo Bar}}}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\small \textcolor{Text}{\textrm{Supervisor:}}} \\
    {\normalsize \textcolor{Text}{\textrm{Prof. Foo Bar Baz}}}
  \end{minipage}
}

\title{An interesting topic}% used on every page
\author[Me]{\usebox{\authbox}}
\institute{A university}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,1cm);
    \node[white] at (0.5\linewidth,0.5cm) {\Large\textsf{An interesting topic}};
    \node[below,align=center] at (0.25\textwidth,-1cm) {Candidate:\\[4pt] Foo Bar};
    \node[below,align=center] at (0.75\textwidth,-1cm) {Supervisor:\\[4pt] Prof. Foo Bar Baz};
    \node at (0.5\linewidth, -3cm) {\footnotesize A university};
    \node at (0.5\linewidth, -4cm) {\today};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```